# Facing Problems In Birt Integration

Tags: birt

In Our Project, we are using Eclipse Link 2.4.2(JPA 2.0),JBOSS 5.1 GA and Sun JDK 6.When i am integrating a birt report(2.5) through ODA-connection.It was throwing some errors like open-Connection cannot be estabilshed.
I am facing three types of problems with birt report.There are :

- Unable to connect to database.
- When the same birt report was executed in Ubuntu environment,i am able to view report with connection exceptions.When i am executing same build in oracle linux environment,it was throwing date format exceptions.
- We have two clients,who uses the same birt reports.but one client uses oracle database and other one is sql server.So we are creating two birt reports for each client.Birt will support to write JPA Queries connecting to Eclipse link.So that i can run in both the environments.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What's the full stack trace your getting when running these reports? The default date format for both of those DB's *should* be YYYY-MM-DD, did you change the default date format of either of them?